# Numpy error in mtrand.pyx file

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-14.04, keras

I was running a Keras model in my desktop, which was running smoothly in my laptop. But in desktop it's giving me the following error:

```
 File "mtrand.pyx", line 1252, in mtrand.RandomState.uniform (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:12988)
 OverflowError: Range exceeds valid bounds
```

My editor is showing that the error is occurring on this line:

```
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
```

Comment: Laptop 64-bit and Desktop 32-bit? What do you mean by running a keras model? Running the code, loading a pickled-model and run? There is probably more information to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a difference in Keras versions between your laptop and desktop. See [Keras issue #2681](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2681). The fix is likely with updating the `input_shape()` method call, whose parameters have changed, to something like this:

```
input_shape=(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH,1)
```

If that does not work, you can try changing the dimension ordering of your images:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Both of these solutions were reported to work for folks experiencing this issue.